# Cofactors of $n \times n$ matrix

Tags: matrices

How do I prove for a matrix $M=({m_{ij})}$ with cofactors ${C_{ij}}$ that
$${m_{i1}}{C_{j1}} + {m_{i2}}{C_{j2}} + ... + {m_{in}}{C_{jn}} = 0$$

I think you use the fact that the determinant can be found by expansion by a row...

Comment: This is only accurate if $i \ne j$. Can you write down a matrix that that would be the determinant of?

Comment: Yes, my book actually says that. Sorry I didn't include it.
No, I can't. I'm not really sure what cofactors are.

Comment: What do you do when you expand a determinant using a given row?

Comment: I don't, that was a hint in the book.

Comment: I think it's going to be hard to explain over the internet. I suggest you look at some examples of how determinants are expanded by rows in a textbook, paying special attention to the meaning of "cofactor" and how cofactors are used. Then return to the problem.

Comment: Can you write out the proof here so I can save this webpage and then after I've really gone over linear algebra (I'm going right back to the start because I keep having difficulties so it will take some time), I'll try to prove it and then see if mine matches yours and if it doesn't whether mine is more or less powerful etc. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe somebody else will do that. But I would prefer it if you came back and edited your question so discussions can focus on where you're having trouble.